# How to get in same table information from previous period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime
DECLARE @enddate datetime

/* HARD CODE 1 WEEK DATA */
SET @startdate = '2016-07-10 00:00:00'
SET @enddate = DATEADD(DAY, 7, @startdate)
SET @enddate = DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, @enddate)
/* HARD CODE 1 WEEK DATA */

SELECT COUNT(0) as registered
FROM member_request ma
WHERE ma.createddate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

This return the total records registered in that periord of time, I would like to get in the same result another columns that will give me the total records but for the previous week.

I know I can do extra select and `UNION ALL` them but maybe there is a better way to do it.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract one week:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as registered
FROM member_request ma
WHERE ma.createddate BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -1, @startdate) AND DATEADD(week, -1, @enddate);
```

If you want both in the same query, the use conditional aggregation

```
select sum(case when ma.createddate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate then 1 else 0
           end) as thisweek,
       sum(case when ma.createddate BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -1, @startdate) AND DATEADD(week, -1, @enddate) then 1 else 0
           end) as lastweek
from member_request ma
where ma_createddate >= DATEADD(week, -1, @startdate);
```

Note:  Using `between` with date/time value.  Aaron Bertrand has an informative blog on why not to do it, [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I think there is a missed THEN and ELSE and THEN in the second SUM

Answer (score 2):

You could use  conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN ma.createddate 
          BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate THEN 1 END) AS current_week
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ma.createddate 
          BETWEEN @startdate - 7 AND @enddate - 7 THEN 1 END) AS prev_week
FROM member_request ma
WHERE ma.createddate BETWEEN @startdate - 7 AND @enddate;
```

`WHERE` - filters 2 weeks range

`COUNT(CASE WHEN ... END)` counts only rows in 1 week range